# Verilog 4-bit up-down counter designed using negative edge triggered T flip flops

Tags: verilog, flip-flop, icarus, iverilog

I'm very new to Verilog HDL and I have to code this 4bit up down counter. With the help of some reading on up-down counters and t flipflops, I already made the following code:

```
module up_down_4bitcounter (
out,
up_down,
clk,
data,
reset
);

//Output Ports
output [3:0] out;

//Input Ports
input [3:0] data;
input up_down, clk, reset;

//Internal Variables
reg [3:0] out;

//Start of Code
always @(negedge clk)
if (reset) begin // active high reset
out <= 4'b0 ;
end else if (up_down) begin
out <= out + 1;
end else begin
out <= out - 1;
end

endmodule
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

```
Exercise5_1.v:25: syntax error
Exercise5_1.v:25: error: unmatched character (')
Exercise5_1.v:25: error: malformed statement
```

Line 25 is this one:

```
out <= 4'b0 ;
```

I am not 100% sure if my coding is correct. Can you tell me where my issue is?

Comment: I've compiled your code in 3 different versions of Icarus Verilog and I couldn't reproduced this error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems I have an excess " ' " in my code. Though, Im not sure how I can test my code. Is my code in the right track? Sorry, just got into Verilog recently.

Comment: It looks quite ok, if you want to have synchronous reset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Qiu, really appreciate it. Yup the professor said the code is correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
Line 25 is this one:
```

There is an error at line 25:

```
out <= 4'b0 ;
```

Answer is:

```
Out <= 4'b0000 ;
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  There is no error in the code in the Question; it is correct syntax.  But you just  created an error by changing `out` to `Out`.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is fine, you can simulate it [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Waj). One option is changing the `out <= 4'b0;` to `out <= 0;`, and if it works there is something wrong with either your editor or simulator.